# Restricting customers to max of 2 purchases for a certain product in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I currently have an issue trying to restrict customers to purchasing 2 of a product max.

So far, I can set the max number of the product in the cart to 2 using catalog/manage products, select the product, then inventory and adjusting the max Qty allowed in cart to 2.

However, this will not stop the user coming back another day and purchasing another 2 items.

What I would like to do is create a rule so that when the user logs in and tries to purchase the product, after already purchasing it, the code will throw an error saying that they have reached their max quantity and prevent the cart from processing the order.

I believe that I would have to edit one of the php files to run a check against the users id and the product id, but I am unsure which file will need to be edited.

Magento ver. 1.3.2.4

Links that helped me, hope it helps:

[step 1](http://www.techflirt.com/how-to-createn-custom-magento-module-step-by-step-tutorial/)
[step 2](http://www.techflirt.com/magento-event-observer-hook-in-magento/)

Comment: First off, you never edit any file in the core, because at any future update your changes will be overwritten. The solution would be to create a custom extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create one observer `checkout_cart_add_product_before`

In this observer event check cart quantity of product, you can get qoute item from quote object and from quote retrieve product quantity and match with newly added product if condition satisfied then redirect customer to product details page with mesage

Comment: Thanks for your reply, after a bit of research, i will need to create a module, then create an event observer, is this correct? I will take a look.

Comment: Yes that is correct. It's perhaps not as easy as an existing module, but it allows for the feature you wish for.

Comment: This seems to be the way to go and not too difficult either. I have added 2 links to my question that helped me do this, hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

To support future compatibility and prevent your changes from being overwritten you should create a custom extension that hooks into the core.

You might try the hook: `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` or `checkout_cart_add_product_before` and test the number of items of each product. Based on that result you might automatically remove the item and parse an error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, are there any plugins/extensions that handle this already? I am new to Magento and looking for a quick fix